# Pubnub webrtc to make Videocalls

Tags: android, webrtc, pubnub

I am working on pubnub to integrate Video calling in my app. I am trying to connect one person with another from a list of random users.

Followed this link : [pubnub-webrtc-github](https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-tutorial)

Using the above link i can video chat in a demo application, 
but when i follow the same in my main project, i get `duplicateEntry : org/webrtc/VideoCapture`

I am already using pubnub as library in my project which has a class `PubNub` < containing a method `publish()`

But for video chat i am using a variable of class `Pubnub` which has a method `publish(String channel, JSONObject message, Callback callback)`

**please note above both pubnubs are different class, they have different class names, Pubnub and PubNub.**

follow below pictures to see `pubnub-library gradle` and `app-gradle`.

**pubnub-lib-gradle**

[image: pubnub-lib-gradle]

**App gradle**

[image: app-gradle]

Answer (score 0):

That's an older version you are using.  I recommend using V1 WebRTC SDK because it is stable and works consistently.  There is a V2 SDK but it has some instabilities.

> You can find PubNub V1 WebRTC SDK here: https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk/blob/master/js/webrtc.js and make sure to [read the docs!](https://github.com/stephenlb/)

The WebRTC Simple Calling API + Mobile SDK is a simplified approach to RTCPeerConnection for mobile and web video calling apps.

Comment: PubNub Android SDK v3 docs: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/pubnub-java-sdk-v3